# min(value) and Max(value) for the particular modified date

Tags: sql-server

How to Get a Min and Max column value for the Modified date

I want to select top and bottom column value for the particular date.

**Table:**

```
 **DATE**     **MODIFIED DATE**  **VALUE**

03:02:2009  04:02:2009  100
03:02:2009  04:02:2009  200
03:02:2009  04:02:2009  400
04:02:2009  05:02:2009  150
04:02:2009  05:02:2009  200
04:02:2009  05:02:2009  500
```

In my Table - Date Column and Value column is there

How can i get min(value) and Max(value) for the particular modified date?

Modified date should be n number of date, suppose am giving from this modified date to 
this modifed date

I want output like this

```
MODIFIED DATE   MIN VALUE   MAX VALUE
04:02:2009  100 400
05:02:2009  150 500
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT ModifiedDate, MIN(Value), MAX(Value)
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY ModifiedDate
ORDER BY ModifiedDate
```

---

edit re comment; it isn't clear how you want to calculate `ModifiedDate`, but for a simple formula, just inline it:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date) AS [ModifiedDate], MIN(Value), MAX(Value)
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, 1, Date)
ORDER BY DATEADD(day, 1, Date)
```

For something more complex, anything from:

- table variables (@table)
- temporary tables (#table)
- sub-queries
- etc

Comment: No modified date column is not in the datebase, Modified date column is created at run time,  so how to get first and last row of the particular modified date

Comment: Well, how do I calculate Modified? It isn't clear from the question.

Comment: For Your Query, 
Min value and Max value is not displaying according to 
Modified Date column,  It is displaying accoring to Date Column only


Date, Modified Date, Value  - 3 columns in my table
Date and Value column direclty displaying from the table at the time of executing the query
Modified Date is displaying at the time of executing the query, it is not in the table
Then How to get a min(value) and Max(value) for the particular modified date

Comment: In both examples I am using ModifiedDate; in what way am I using Date?

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell,

Table

```
DATE    VALUE
22:02:2009  200
22:02:2009  400
22:02:2009  100
24:02:2009  250
24:02:2009  400
24:02:2009  800
```

(Select Date,  … from table)

While executing the above query, below mentioned table is displaying

```
DATE    MODIFIED DATE   VALUE
22:02:2009  23:02:2009  200
22:02:2009  23:02:2009  400
22:02:2009  23:02:2009  100
24:02:2009  25:02:2009  250
24:02:2009  25:02:2009  400
24:02:2009  25:02:2009  800
```

Here leave the date column; exactly I need min (value) and max (value) for the Modified Date

Output I need like this

```
DATE    MN VALUE    MAX VALUE
22:02:2009  200 100
24:02:2009  250 800
```

Note: Don’t evaluate the column value, only I need top value and bottom value for the particular date.

Comment: You haven't added **anything** there that helps me understand the question, and therefore help more. Worse: you've added confusion - the new results don't seem to involve modified-date, and the results don't seem to make sense (why wouldn't 400 be the max for 22:02:2009?). I've given two approaches - if neither fits, you're going to have to say why. We're not psychic, and we can't read your screen from here.

Comment: If we used min and max means it display only min and max value
I need Top column value and Bottom Column Value for the Modified date

ex:  Modified Date column value is - 200, 100, 400, 600, 500

Need Only - 100 and 500 by using sub query

Comment: Am using sub query in that i need Top and Bottom Value for the Modified date

Comment: tables are not naturally ordered unless you add a sort. There *is* no real meaning of top/bottom, unless you add something like an auto-increment identity column.